# Cron'ing PHP scripts that write to other files.

Tags: php

So the client I am working for right now is really big on load time speed, so we try to shave every micro second possible. We found a file the other day that was pulling some word press blogs and it was adding a solid second to the load time.

Now I didn't write that particular script and perhaps I can go optimize it later, but for now, what I did was make a script that writes the output of the wp script to another file, then I simply reference that file when we need it. We run a cron on the script I wrote so it checks the wp script every so often and outputs any updates if needed.

That obviously really made things faster but I just have never done it before so I am curious about it:

- obviously we have a file with 777 permissions, what are my security concerns for this?
- Is this a good strategy to cut down in the future when the processing doesn't have to be done at the time of load?

Comment: Related:  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/137860/34530

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you shouldn't have 777 permissions on that file. change the file to be owned by the user your apache (or whatever webserver you're using) is running (for example `wwwrun.www` on suse linux or `www-data.www` on ubuntu). after this you can give read and write permissions just to that user (`644`) - you don't need permissions for executing at all.

**EDIT:**
the commands to do this are

- `chown wwwrun.www myfile.txt` to change the owning user (`wwwrun`) and user-group (`www`)
- `chmod 644 myfile.txt` to change the permissions (`6` = read/write for owner, `44` = just reading for everyone else)

Comment: I may need a little clarification on how to do this. Obviously changing permissions is not an issue, but I am unclear on "change the file to be owned by the user your apache is running" Learning something new every day, still very green on some of this server stuff.

Comment: please see my edit and don't hesitate to ask if anything else remained unclear

Comment: excellent, thanks so much. I'll post more questions if I run into any trouble.